# getting between square bracket having specific characteristic using Boost regex in C++ not getting answer

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-regex

I have a string like this:

```
This is a link [[abcd 1234|xyz 1234]]  [[India]] [[abcd 1234|xyz 1234]]
```

and I want to get :

```
This is a link abcd 1234 [[India]] abcd 1234
```

I want to take double square brackets having | and take out things that are before | and replace it with whole double square bracket thing and not replace any double square bracket not having | using Boost Regex.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: 1. `I want to take double square brackets having | and take out things that are before | and replace it with whole double square bracket thing and not replace any double square bracket not having | using Boost Regex.` This sentence makes no sense... 2. I think regexs are probably not the way to go here, they're not good for matching up opening/closing brackets.

Comment: With regexs I always wonder if there is a better way to do it. And I was bored, so I came up with a way just using `std::string` facilities. I'll let you decide if it's better or not, but [here it is](http://ideone.com/hJyhJ4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the look-ahead, `(?!pattern)`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "This is a link [[abcd 1234|xyz 1234]]  [[India]] [[abcd 1234|xyz 1234]]";
    boost::regex re("\\[\\[(((?!\\]\\]).)+)\\|.*?]]");
    std::cout << boost::regex_replace(str, re, "$1") << '\n';
}
```

demo: http://liveworkspace.org/code/2Mu5cN

Comment: Thanks you made my day can you similarly provide regex for getting xyz 1234 in place of abcd 1234 in string??

Comment: @PragneshPatel No tricks there, just capture (surround with parentheses) the `.*?` after the `|` and change the number in `$1` (to `$3` in this case)

Comment: Sorry to again take your time can you tell how to just extract those values using boost if no replacement is required question is what to do with regex

Comment: @PragneshPatel To extract individual submatches, I would use `regex_token_iterator`

Answer (score 0):

```
"\\[\\[(.*?)\|.*?]]"
```

This will match text between `[[` and `]]` with a `|` separator. `$1` is the text between the `[[` and the `|`.

Comment: @PeteBecker [[India]] get selected and it substitute as India]] [[abcd 1234 that is the main issue I also tried same thing that you told before asking the question Thanks for your time

Comment: @BoBTFish can we do something that if after [[ if ]] is encountered before | than that does not match with regex??

Comment: @BoBTFish I thought that `*?` (as opposed to just `*`) would be the opposite of greedy.

Comment: @PragneshPatel Instead of `.*?` in the capture group, try `[^]|]*?`.